# JavaScript and Visibility

Tags: javascript, html, hidden

I'm **new** to JavaScript and now I'm having this problem: When I launch the webpage the "btn" is invisible (hidden), but I need it to be visible until mousedown. Here is the script:

```
var start= false;
var racket = document.getElementById("racket");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.style.visibility = "visible";
btn.onmousedown = Start();

function Start() {
    btn.style.visibility = "hidden";
    start = true;
    document.onclick = RacketClick();
}

function RacketClick() {

}
```

When I launch the webpage, the btn is hidden... Can you help me?

**UPD 1** HTML code and CSS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Main</title>
        <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="/js/mymain.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="racket"></div>
        <div id="btn"></div>
    </body>
</html>

#racket {
    top: 100%;
    margin-top: -200px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -77px;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url('/images/racket.png');
    width: 154px;
    height: 250px;
    animation-name: racketanimation;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-direction:alternate;
}

@keyframes racketanimation {
    from {
        transform: rotateX(40deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotateX(55deg);
    }
}

#btn {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -128px;
    margin-left: -128px; 
    height: 256px; 
    width: 256px;
    background-image: url('/images/playnowborder.png');
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-name: clicken;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes clicken {
    from {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

I'm new to this website too! I would liked your answers, but I don't have reputation to vote...

Comment: Did you hide it with CSS ?

Comment: No I didn't, I have problems with JavaScript (not with HTML and CSS)

Comment: `document.onclick = RacketClick` && `btn.onmousedown = Start`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use your function assignment without parenthesis:

```
btn.onmousedown = Start;
```

Otherwise function `Start` got executed at the moment of assignment and your button becomes hidden immediately.

Answer (score 1):

This line is your problem:

```
btn.onmousedown = Start();
```

You are executing the function start and assigning the result (`undefined`) to `btn.onmousedown`. You should have:

```
btn.onmousedown = Start;
```

Without parenthesis, to assign the function, not call the function.